# API for sending text messages from web application to cell phones in Canada

Tags: api, service, sms

I have to send text message reminder to cell phone of a customer. That should be handled from web application (or automated with windows service). Text message should be sent to Canadian cell phone and provider of that phone is not exactly known beforehand (can be Bell, Telus or anything else).

Is there any reliable API provider for such task? I need a web service that would be integrated with .NET application for doing it and it should be either free or inexpensive. I did Google search on the topic and it seems there some providers out there but it would be really great to hear from somebody who can have real experience with such API provider. My goal is to send about 10000 remainders per month.

I would appreciate if you could advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Anvar, Can you advise on the solution you found. I have the same problem. I need a provider for Canada and the US.

Answer (score 2):

I have had good luck with [TextMarks](http://www.textmarks.com/).  You pick a keyword that your users send in an SMS message to the TextMarks shortcode number.  This confirms that the mobile user has opted in to receive SMS messages from you.  You can then send them SMS messages and even create programs that respond to a users input.  For example, have the user send a zip code and get a response of stores nearby.  They are relatively inexpensive and offer various tiers of pricing, including a free trial option.

I also came across ClickATell which is able to provide you with a unique shortcode.  However, last time I checked getting a unique shortcode was in the range of $500 per month plus costs you would incur to send messages.  Here's their pricing calculator:

http://www.clickatell.com/pricing/pricing_wizard.php

Comment: Thanks John, text mark looks interesting although it does not look like they support integration with .NET.

Comment: TextMarks has recently added .NET support (as well as Python, PHP, Java, ...). See: http://www.textmarks.com/dev/docs/api2client/dotnet/

Answer (score 1):

TextMarks doesn't work in Canada, but we do have a .NET API wrapper that we just released.  If you were looking for this for the US, we could help you.

Comment: Chris, I think I found what I need and it works in Canada as well as in US. Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it.